# Why am I getting error in Spring basic application?

Tags: java, spring

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/c
ore/io/Resource
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetMethodRecursive(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.validateMainClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.core.io.Resourc
e
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 7 more
```

I am learning spring ..So just I have created basic Spring application..

And I've complied all classes (Student Model Class + Test Class contains Main method) using command prompt
and also created applicationContext.xml.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your classpath if 
**spring-core** is added. He seems to didn't find it.
(Project properties  > Java Build Path > Librairies)

If you're using Maven to manage dependencies, add in your *pom.xml* :

```
<dependency>
 <groupid>org.springframework</groupid>
 <artifactid>spring-core</artifactid>
 <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have added following dependency into pom.xml file :

```
 <dependency>
     <groupid>org.springframework</groupid>
     <artifactid>spring-core</artifactid>
     <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
  </dependency>
```

Comment: I am not using Maven

Comment: @Niks is asking you to get this library and put in classpath. If not mavven then download from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core and add to classpath in IDE.

Comment: Yes Keval as per @Sheetal Mohan Sharma saying first download this jar file and add it to your build path libraries.